# Disable Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) in brave browser

Tags: python, ajax, cross-origin-read-blocking, brave

I am serving static content (html, css and js) using [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/). I want to call api from  a server hosted on the localhost using a wsgi application with python. I am getting the following error when I am trying to call the api from frontend (using ajax with jquery library).
[image: error screenshot]

I am accessing the site via [brave browser](https://brave.com/). For testing purpose how can I disable this "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response" feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent MIME sniffing by setting the response header option `X-Content-Type-Options` to `nosniff`.
For lighttpd the syntax is:

```
setenv.add-response-header = ("X-Content-Type-Options" => "nosniff",)
```

Comment: Thanks, but more importantly than adding "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" response header, I had to make sure that the correct "Content-Type" response header for the served resource was set, e.g. for the site's favicon I gotta set it to `Content-Type: image/x-icon`.